# not able to fetch data from only one route from react to express

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to make an e-commerce website and I am fetching data from the backend in react . I am getting the data from the backend except for the route http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/6173d16a7037921b98ec9777

This is my code for server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const connect = require("./connect");
const UserRouter = require("./routers/UserRouters");
const ProductRouter = require("./routers/ProductRouters");
const app = express();

// using routes middleware
app.use("/api/users", UserRouter);
app.use("/api/products", ProductRouter);

// routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.send("App is running on port 5000");
});



app.listen("5000", () => {
 console.log("App is running on port http://localhost:5000");
});
```

ProductRouter.js

```
const express = require("express");
const products = require("../Data").products;
const Product = require("../models/productModel");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const router = express.Router();

router.get(
  "/",
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const add_product = await Product.find({});
   if (add_product) {
    res.status(200).send(add_product);
    console.log("product added successfully : ", add_product);
   } else {
  res.status(404).send({ error: "something went wrong" });
  console.log(
    "Something went wrong while sending the prodcut data : ",
    error
  );
}
})
);

router.get(
 "/:id",
asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
// getting the products
const { id } = req.params;
const all_products = await Product.findById({ _id: id });
console.log("id : ", id);

// sending the products
if (all_products) {
  console.log("products : ", all_products);
  res.send(all_products);
 } else {
  res.status(404).send({ message: "Product Not Found" });
 }
   })
    );
   router.get(
    "/seed",
   asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   const add_product = await Product.insertMany(products);
    if (add_product) {
     res.status(200).send(add_product);
     console.log("product added successfully : ", add_product);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ error: "Something went wrong" });
    console.log(
      "Something went wrong while sending the prodcut data : ",
      error
    );
  }
     })
     );

module.exports = router;
```

ProductAction.js

```
import {
 PRODUCT_ADD_TO_CART,
 PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAILURE,
 PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
 PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
 PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE,
 PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
 PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
} from "../Constants/productConstants";

// setting actions for data at HomeScreen
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
  try {
    const res = await fetch("/api/products/${productId}", {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "Application/Json",
     },
   });
   const data = await res.json();
   console.log("Product Data : ", data);
   dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
 } catch (error) {
 dispatch({ PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE, payload: error });
 }
};

// fetching data for the Product Details screen
export const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  // dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/products/${productId}/`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "Application/Json",
      },
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log("products details Data : ", data);
  dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(
    "Something went wrong while fetching products details : ",
   error
 );
 dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAILURE, payload: error });
 }
};
```

I am able to fetch data for "/" route but not for "/:id"
Please help !!

Comment: what is the `${productId}` in `"/api/products/${productId}"`  in `listProducts` . also in the `detailsProduct` fetch try removing the last `/`

Comment: ${ProductId} is the id of the product you can see in the url and I have tried removing the "/"  but its still not working , I think the problem is in productRouter.js or server.js

Comment: but it is trying to call `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/${productId}"` since here `${productId}` is just a string